# How to edit an Open Graph Object's facebook page via the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Via the Graph API...

...I want to be able to edit page data like:

- the Info tab
- add a profile tab
  (I successfully installed an app on the page via the "**{page_id}/tabs?app_id...**" call but it doesn't show up as a profile tab, not does it come back in the list of tabs in the response to the "**{page_id}/tabs**" call.)
- -display my custom namespace properties on the page

...I would also love to be able to:

- check in to the page using built-in Facebook checkins, not my custom namespace checkins

Answer (score 1):

Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs you can HTTP Post your updates using /PAGE_ID/tabs/TAB_ID, HTTP Delete your tab, HTTP post a new tab using PAGE_ID/tabs

You will need to get a page access token from the admin of the page to do any of those. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens